# How to ignore the rows with empty values?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this;

```
id | FName | LName  | Age
1  | John  | KK     | 32
2  | Harry |        | 
3  | Mary  | Simons | 
4  |       |        |
```

Here in this table i need to select all the rows except the one with id 4 and all the rows like this having only primary key and other data empty.

Comment: I suspect that you're capable of asking a better question than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `IS NOT NULL` predicate with `OR`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE FName IS NOT NULL
   OR LName IS NOT NULL
   OR Age   IS NOT NULL;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00a233/1)**:

```
| id | FName |  LName |    Age |
|----|-------|--------|--------|
|  1 |  John |     KK |     32 |
|  2 | Harry | (null) | (null) |
|  3 |  Mary | Simons | (null) |
```

Comment: thanks man this worked...I tried with and so did not worked...cheers

Comment: @RajKumar yes OR will work that is why i removed my answer

Comment: @RajKumar - You're welcome, please accept the answer if you found it helpful.